# How to handle a question mark in symfony 2 route

Tags: symfony

I use jquery ui autocomplete with a dynamic source:

```
 $( "#shop-id" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/app_dev.php/ticket/get_sids/",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

The produced url will look like this:

```
/app_dev.php/ticket/get_sids/?term=22
```

How do I handle that in symfony 2 routing? I tried several things but the question mark seems to be the bottle neck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`term=22` is a query parameter — a parameter that comes with a `GET` request. Symfony will not use this while checking the route, so it will try to find a route for `/ticket/get_sids/`. If you define a controller that handles this URL, then you can get the `term` parameter like this:

```php
$term = $request->query->get('term');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a route like this:

```
ajax_ticket_autocomplete_search:
    pattern:  /ticket/get_sids.php
    defaults: { _controller: "YOURBundle:Ticket:ajaxSearchTicket" }
```

and in your ticket controller:

```
public function ajaxSearchTicketAction()
    {

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $term_autocomplete=$request->query->get('term');
    ...
```

in this way you can access to the term value, by querystring.